# Targeting Java 6 with Java 9 JDK gives warnings

Tags: java, gradle, java-9, release-management, java-10

I'm trying to build a project using JDK 9, as using the `--release` argument to javac means it can build for older versions without needing the corresponding JDK/JRE installed. I need to support Java 6 so my preexisting set up requires Java 6 for the bootstrapClasspath and a further JDK 8 or 9 for gradle and the IDE. I'd like to eliminate JDK 6 in favor of just using 9, and tidy the build somewhat.

My new build.gradle has the following configuration:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs.addAll(['--release', '6', "-Xlint"])
}
```

The `sourceCompatibility`, `targetCompatibility` and `bootstrapClasspath` options are not set, as I understand the `--release` argument handles this now.

I get the following warnings:

```
warning: [options] source value 1.6 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 1.6 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
```

I know these can be suppressed (it says it right there), but I wasn't expecting to see them.
When building with `--release [7-9]` these warnings are not present.

For context, this is the old (unused now) '2x JDK' config:

```
sourceCompatibility = "1.6"
targetCompatibility = "1.6"

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.bootstrapClasspath = new SimpleFileCollection(Arrays.asList(new File("$JDK6_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar")))
}
```

Am I setting the compiler arguments incorrectly? Is there a way to not set / unset `source` and `target`?

Comment: It just warns that targeting Java6 might stop working with new releases of JDK8/9+ and it doesn't matter if you use `-source` && `-target` or the new `--release`.

Comment: --release is basically shorthand for -source -target -bootclasspath
Might be that it uses those flags under the hood or sees them as similair. Hence the warnings.

Comment: @user158037 why wouldn't it also warn for Java 7 though?

Comment: @trappski wouldn't it be reasonable to expect it uses those flags for the other versions (7,8) too? They don't give warnings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though this is not from an official source, yet the warning seems to be aligned with the *"one plus three back"* clause as stated in the 
***[JEP182#Policy for Retiring javac -source and -target Options](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/182)***

> JDK 9 will implement a "one plus three back" support policy meaning
>   that 1.9/9, 1.8/8, 1.7/7, and 1.6/6 will be recognized in that
>   release. That policy will continue in JDK 10.

<strike>So ideally 1.6 should be removed with JDK10 in picture with the warning taking in good effect for clients to be aware of the policy.</strike>

***Edit:*** Yet, as pointed by [Alan in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814806/targetting-java-6-with-java-9-jdk-gives-warnings/47815517?noredirect=1#comment82593066_47815517)
**JDK 10 will continue to support `--release 6`**
as stated in [this mailiing list.](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk-dev/2017-December/000321.html)

Comment: JDK 10 will continue to support `--release 6`. More on this here: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk-dev/2017-December/000321.html

Comment: @AlanBateman Would update the answer with the same. Hopefully that should serve as an official confirmation as well. :)